# IE jquery doesn't load

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer

I'm working on a Wordpress website and I have a problem with IE. It seems like it doesn't load jQuery at all, because all the jQuery functions don't work. And it even messes up the whole site. It looks as it should in Chrome and FF, but IE really messes it up and none of the animations & sliders work.

It's even stranger that it worked fine when it was just a plain html file with css and some jquery functions... since I integrated it in Wordpress it's all messed up. Did someone have a problem like this before? Please help.. maybe it's just a minor error i'm not seeing or something...

here's the link to the website http://matoweb.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the console (F12) to see what error you're getting:

```
    nextText: "Next",               
});
```

IE does not support leading commas in object literals if they don't follow another property.

Comment: thanks for your help. jQuery works now but it's still messed up... why is that? i tried everything but nothing works...

Comment: @matejlatin: Somehow IE uses quirks mode for your page. If you select IE9 document mode manually in the console then things look fine. Try removing the invisible character (`\u65279`) before your doctype.

Comment: there is no space before the doctype in the code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>

Comment: @matejlatin: Perhaps you don't see it in your editor. Hit backspace before the `<!` (but NOT at the start of the line) to make sure it is removed.

Comment: i can't even save in Notepad++ because there's no change :) that space before the doctype is there only in IE source view...

Comment: @matejlatin: Are you sure? I can see it if I copy the source from Chrome into my editor. If you go to the very start of the file (using `Home` key perhaps), then you should be able to press `Delete` once to remove the character.

Comment: you're right.. there's a line break and a ? before the doctype in chrome source but i can't find any of these in my source...

Comment: @matejlatin: If you're not able to remove it, then try adding a line break before the doctype. Perhaps IE will treat the doctype as being separate from the character in that case.

Comment: wow i googled a little and found this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/weird-characters-inserted-before-doctype

you were right the whole time... some strange characters were added before the doctype and that's what messed up the design... thanks a lot pimvdb! i owe you a beer ;)

Comment: @matejlatin: I'd rather have a green tick next to this answer :) Glad you solved it.

Comment: +1s for the comments, I looked at this problem and couldn't work out why IE was going in to Quirks mode.